# `sudo apt upgrade` shows broken packages

Tags: package-management, login, .desktop, partial-upgrade

I have a 32-bit Asus laptop with an i386 processor.
I had installed *Ubuntu 16.04 LTS* then I upgraded/updated it to *Ubuntu 18.04 LTS*.  After updating it to *Ubuntu 18.04 LTS*  the desktop was not showing anything; like it was not showing taskbar, *etc.*, it was just blank and I was not able to open any application.

I entered the command to update then it said 846 packages remaining to upgrade so I tried upgrading, and it shows it found **Broken packages**.  How can I overcome such a problem?

When I rebooted the system it showed *16.04 LTS Ubuntu* but when i opened  *tty* terminal using command *Ctrl+Alt+f1* there it showed *ubuntu 18.04 Lts*.  What's the issue?

Comment: Please [add](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1229883/edit) to your question above the complete output of `sudo apt update` and of `sudo apt upgrade`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)

Answer (score 0):

Usually `sudo apt --fix-broken install` should fix it.